# How to access super high voice range?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training

I'm a 20 year old guy,

I was wondering if I could possibly expend my vocal range up to the 6th octave 
in any way ? I can go from G2 to G5 with the piano

Would it be possible to hit like up to a C6 ?

I've seen people say that it's impossible for male to reach those high notes 
and others who say you just have to practice a lot but it's reachable for anyone...

Anyone has an idea? Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I've seen people misidentify the octaves before on this type of question, so be certain that you have the correct notes (C6 is the "Soprano High C", and should sound really high). If you have the correct octave numbers, proceed.

---

**It's definitely not impossible for males to sing C6.** Michael Jackson in *Smooth Criminal*, anyone? Prince? Freddie Mercury's done it as well. There are more examples than just them, of course, and amateur singers sometimes have that note as well. Plenty of regular males can in fact go there and higher, and I know one who can.

He can sing C6 pretty much on command, and at his highest ever, he's sung C7. He says that while he's not sure whether *anyone* can hit C6 with practice, it certainly can't hurt to practice falsetto a lot as long as you're not doing something wrong.

He and every other (post-adolescent) male I've seen who can do it (and for that matter, females) use falsetto to get up that high. He also says that *he notices that he tends to be able to go highest when he's excited, such as on a rollercoaster or cheering in a crowd, so **perhaps adrenaline helps**.* In my very limited experience, the males who can do that up that high tend to be baritone voices, but I doubt that that's a hard-and-fast rule at all. (There's also a phenomon called whistle register, but that apparently is even more ridiculously rare for males).

It's always tricky advising people on how to extend their vocal range. The thing I usually recommend would be to **practice** (and make sure you're not injuring your voice, as always!), and **consider finding a vocal instructor**. I find that the more one sings in falsetto, the easier control gets, and usually the easier it gets to produce the higher notes.

One final note: The extremities of the male falsetto range can sound very unpleasant if done without control, and that's a common issue with the male falsetto register in general. It's rare nowadays to hear a male singer with such control over the extreme high range of his falsetto as to be able to use it musically (in fact, it's uncommon for female singers too).

Comment: Just as a nice addition, Myles Kennedy (singer with Alter Bridge, Slash etc) has a sung range of Bb1 to D6 and a total range up to F#6 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xkOJ_AfbqQ

Comment: Maybe I'll make my way up to those notes someday but I'm still far from it anyway... 
The range Myles Kennedy can sing in is very impressing ! I didn't know he could go up that high, that's astounding
I really wonder how he trained his vocal cords to be able to make those kind of sound moreover how to use that in performance.

Thank you for this answer, I learned quite a lot actually!